# Dependency Injection. Feel like I'm injecting the same object more than once

Tags: php, oop

In the application I am coding myself (MVC) I am using dependency injection to pass an object its dependencies. I don't want to use the Singleton pattern or a dependency injection container.

When the application starts up it has some procedural code instantiating important objects like this: (It loads up more objects than below but they should be enough to explain what I am on about)

```
/*
* ------------------------------------------------------
* INSTANTIATE THE APPLICATION CLASS
* ------------------------------------------------------
*/
$app = new App();
$app->environment('development');


/*
* ------------------------------------------------------
* INSTANTIATE THE CONFIGURATION CLASS
* ------------------------------------------------------
*/
$config = new Config();


/*
* ------------------------------------------------------
* INSTANTIATE THE LOGGER CLASS
* ------------------------------------------------------
*/
$logger = new Logger($config);


/*
* ------------------------------------------------------
* INSTANTIATE THE LOCALE CLASS
* ------------------------------------------------------
*/
$locale = new Locale();


/*
* ------------------------------------------------------
* INSTANTIATE THE HTTP RESPONSE CLASS
* ------------------------------------------------------
*/
$httpResponse = new HttpResponse();


/*
* ------------------------------------------------------
* INSTANTIATE THE ROUTER CLASS
* ------------------------------------------------------
*/
$router = new Router($config, $logger, $httpResponse);
$router->route();
```

As you can see the $logger object depends on the $config object and I inject the $config object into the $logger objects constructor.

Now, as you can see when I am instantiating the $router object it has 3 dependencies ($config, $logger and $httpResponse).

I just feel it's weird how the $logger object holds the $config object within it so anywhere I inject the $config and $logger objects seperately into an object like in the $router object I feel like I'm injecting the $config object twice and that it's wrong.

Obviously when I have more and more objects and dependencies it will seem like I am injecting the same object more than two or three times and that will really make me wonder if I'm doing it wrong.

Is what I'm doing ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats OK, because `$router` does not and should never need to know, whether or not the `$logger` knows `$config` itself. Imagine you want to replace the logger with a dummy

```
class NullLogger { /* "Do nothing" code*/ }
```

This class don't need a configuration, so when `$router` uses the config of `$logger`, it's broken right now :)

Beside this it would be cleaner anyway, when you pass only the configuration, that is associated with the class like `new Logger($config['logger']);` instead of `new Logger($config);`. Why should everybody must now of everything?

Comment: Would it not be more memory efficient to just pass the `$logger` object around instead of copies of different sections of it?

Comment: @jeroen What do you mean with "sections of $logger"?

Comment: I mean one general `$config` object instead of copies in the class itself like `$config['logger']`, etc. I would assume that `$config['logger']` in the `Logger` class creates a copy of the variable (a section of `$config`) while the object is passed by reference.

Comment: I guess `$config` is not an object and anyway `$config['logger']` would not be a copy of it, because a) it's just a part and b) PHP uses copy-on-write. But the real problem is: It seems you prefer a "type-less"-approach before clean code. Everything knows everything and `$config` is coupled with everything. I would even go further and only pass the values (using a factory-method/-class) and not a config: `$logger = FileLogger:create($config);` and there extract the required values from `$config`. After initialization the configuration is not required anymore anyway ;)

Comment: It's not so much what I prefer, I just wonder about it; especially after doing a `var_dump($this)` once in codeignitor that hung my browser...